Failed to download or update Snyk dependencies. "code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY",
I am trying to install snyk extension on VScode. i am getting this error message in output window of VSCode
[Error] Failed to download or update Snyk dependencies. {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY","message":"unable to get local issuer certificate","stack":"Error: unable to get local issuer certificate\n    at Function.AxiosError.from (c:\\Users\\XYZ\\.vscode\\extensions\\snyk-security.snyk-vulnerability-scanner-2.16.0\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:841:14)

we don't want disable proxy. "http.proxyStrictSSL": false"
we don't want disable proxy. "http.proxyStrictSSL": false"

Sounds like this might be an internet or VPN/proxy configuration issue on your end. It's working great for me in VSCode as of today (July 30, 2024).
Typical issues like this are either:

Your connection is being MITM'd and someone is interfering with your TLS (common on corporate VPNs, for example)
Your internet connection in general is having some issues


This should be the correct answer. Please accept if it solved your problem, Kajal. Thanks
